What is the earliest known children's rag doll?
What is the earliest known children's rag doll?
Several sites reference this doll found at Oxyrhynchus in Egypt, dated to between the 1st and 5th centuries CE, as having been found in a child's grave, but the website of the British Museum - where the doll is now located - doesn't confirm this:

Perhaps this doll is the answer to the question. I would agree that if it actually was found in a child's grave it can confidently be called a child's rag doll, and I know of no earlier children's rag dolls.
But perhaps a later doll is an answer to the question.
I suspect that rag dolls are not as ancient as some claim.
A children's rag doll is defined as a doll for children, representing a human being, stuffed with scraps of fabric, papyrus, or other fairly soft or squidgy stuff, rather than being made from, say, wood or stone.

I think this will be a difficult question to answer definitively and a lot will hang on semantics.
Harris (1920) cautions:

By dolls, I mean those toys that are usually given to
children to play with. The religious element does not come
in here, or when it does, the doll ceases to be a doll proper.
The figurines, for instance, placed in Egyptian tombs for
religious purposes, are not dolls at all, though they can easily be mistaken for the real dolls found in children's tombs,
but with entirely different functions. Sometimes the two functions are interchangeable.

McKelderkin (1930) agrees:

Evidently many of the figurines discovered in temple excavations
really served a double purpose, first as playthings and later as offerings, but when we try to separate the toys from the purely dedicatory
objects we are on safe ground only in the case of jointed dolls, and
even these have occasionally been mistaken for idols.

The earliest such jointed dolls, according to McKelderkin, are attributed to Egypt and substantially older than the object pictured in the question, but are made of wood or pottery. As for a rag doll specifically, I can't find anything older than the one in the question. And it's possible, but no means certain, that it was used as a toy and not just a religious offering.
Von Boehn (2020) looks like a good source if you want a deep dive into the overall history of dolls and puppets around the world, but a quick search doesn't yield a decisive answer.
